# Mysql error in select statement for date type column

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT DAY_ADD(DATE(scp.create_date),INTERVAL scp.subscription_period_days  DAYS) 
FROM `subscription` scp;
```

I am getting error as :

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DAYS) FROM `subscription` scp

what would be solution if I am adding days using some column values. should I use some other `mysql` function. Please rectify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT DAY_ADD(scp.create_date,INTERVAL scp.subscription_period_days DAY) 
FROM `subscription` scp;
```

Answer (score 0):

INTERVAL **DAY** instead of DAYS should work better.

Comment: OK then try subscription.subscription_period_days instead of alias. Oh, and DATE_ADD instead of DAY_ADD. If that doesn't work, then I don't know, because it should.